# On the Pauli Principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, pauli-exclusion-principle

[image: A Quantum Mechanical System]

Consider a quantum mechanical system as shown-say a piece of metallic conductor in the shape of a long, thin bar.(Must it be a single crystal to be considered a "system"?). Now focus on two free electrons, one at each end,in states $\hat{s}_1$ and $\hat{s}_2$ respectively. Let $\hat{s}$ be an unoccupied state.

Now suppose we apply a localized transverse electric field at each end, each of sufficient strength to push its associated electron into the unoccupied state $\hat{s}$. We can arrange things so these two transitions are simultaneous in the lab frame.

My question: Which electron wins and occupies $\hat{s}$? Since propagation of "the news" cannot excede $c$, how does the loser know the state is already occupied and therefore has posted a no vacancy sign?

I suppose the question can be rephrased as follows: is the Pauli principle only for stationary systems or is it also valid in the time varying case as well?

This question would appear to be relevent to the perennial problem of finding the speed of an electric current propagating through metallic conductors.

By the way, I have done a search and am aware of several similar questions here, but--frankly--I didn't really understand the answers. I am somewhat familiar with the basic concepts of quantum theory and am fairly competent mathematically, but what I am looking for is a practical, down-to-earth way of thinking about this issue (maybe supported with only a very few equations, if any!).

Thanks.

Comment: Free electrons are delocalised in a piece of conductor so the premise according to which two electrons may be located respectively at each end of a metallic bar seems dubious to me...just saying.

Comment: gatsu: Yes, I understand your thought. It occurred to me too, but then I began to question just what a "quantum system" is. If I have a metallic conductor several meters long, I can certainly localize the exciting fields to the ends. Now if an electron is a completely nonlocal concept, how can I even discuss their propagation from one end to another? I think "nonlocality" must be only applicable to the case of a closed system in equilibrium---and equilibrium means that I can't accelerate the electrons as I wish!?

Comment: In a metal, delocalised electrons have a definite state of motion. In absence of current electrons are as likely to have a given momentum than its opposite and thus no current is flowing. Once you put a potential difference, electrons are more likely to have momenta in a certain direction and electrical current flows. As far as I know, people discuss propagation of charge density perturbations not of electrons themselves. I think it is at the level of charge density that something can be done. Pauli principle appears in the exchange term then.